# Geometric information within 1D streams of electrons/photons

Tags: electron, image-sensor, crt, photonics

How is light—or actually any frequency in the EM spectrum—self-encoding and self-modulating 3D info in its 1D self, so that it “knows,” once it strikes a surface, to discharge all the data perfectly as a 2D image?? It’s not like FM or AM circuitry is being employed here... light is self-modulating to encode 3D scenery data perfectly without external interference to self-induce a modulation.

Comment: Do you know how an old-fashioned TV works? Search for [how+does+analogue+tv+work](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+does+analogue+tv+work) and then refine your question into an aspect that you don't understand. (It's not magic. It's engineering!)

Comment: Yep, I understand it enough so that something makes zero sense with respect to electrons/photons maintaining 2D information within its 1D stream. :)

Comment: Do you understand the term "raster scan"?

Comment: The whole universe might be built from 1D: see [vanishing dimensions](https://www.livescience.com/33228-early-universe-1-d-line-vanishing-dimensions-theory.html). Still earlier you'll find work on 1D Calabi-Yau strings for our universe. And of course there's the suggestion that black holes have 2D surfaces (holograms) that encode everything that's fallen into them, so that 3D objects are mapped onto a 2D surface just fine. There are all kinds of known mathematical ways of encoding what appears to be 3D in only 1D. Who knows? You might be actually 1D but just imagine you see a 3D world...

Comment: Yep, I knnow what a raster scan is... problem is, information is 1D, but consciousness makes a big distinction between 1D information and genuine 2D or 3D spatiality.  There is no known mathematical function that is instructing 1D information to retain 2D or 3D information!  Light and other EM waves are mimetic of the 3D sources it strikes, self-encoding spatial data.  I’m trying to plumb how it’s doing this...

Comment: You say that you understand how raster scan and analog TV works, but from your line of questioning it's pretty clear that you don't. There is no 'self organizing' of 2D into 1D data. A CRT foes not simply fire electons at the phosphor and hope for the best - the electron beam is directed by magnetic fields to scan across the screen.

Comment: The data being encoded is the issue, not the raster scanning.  

It’s more...

Anyone have any idea how light—or actually any frequency in the EM spectrum—is self-encoding and self-modulating 3D info in its 1D self, so that it “knows,” once it strikes a surface, to discharge all the data perfectly as a 2D image?? It’s not like FM or AM circuitry is being employed here... light is self-modulating to encode 3D scenery data perfectly without external interference to self-induce a modulation.  There is no raster scanning in a pin-hole camera.

Comment: Same thing is happening with sound.  A microphone diaphragm “hears” one additive aggregate wave of all the waves in the room.  The signal is “flattened” to maintain every nuance of every overtone.  When converted to binary, the signal can be reconstructed, and maintains deep 3D self-encoded spectrographic data at every section.  The binaries are only representing 1D voltage amplitudes.  How is a speaker reproducing all of that embedded data with only a single wave?  This same data can piggyback a video signal in a satellite signal???    Waves are mobile databases!

Comment: @brhans: Fact: the 1D stream of photons or electrons configuration bear no resemblance to the 2D image it “knows” how to construct after passing through a pin-hole camera hole, refractive lens or a wire

Comment: @jsotola and how is it reconstructed in a pinhole camera with no rasterizing tech?

Comment: User jonk above gets the vibe of the question...

Comment: Maybe the problem is thinking about light as a single entity. If we use the model where light is made of infinitesimal rays, we can apply few simple rules to each ray and see how a collection of those make up an image.

Comment: @chamod But we still have the same issue with other non-visible frequencies.  How would it apply to a 30GHz satellite TV signal that encodes how multiple ~5THz light waves were behaving in a 3D space?

Comment: @JordanFine In the case of a picture encoded in a tv signal, I wouldn't think of it as a 5THz signal contained in there, since we don't need to store information about every photon or light ray. Instead, we only want to encode colour, brightness information about 2million squares (pixels). When the tv recreates these squares, the light generated on the display follows the simple physical rules, which makes us see the same image as it appeared on the image sensor of the camera.

Comment: @chamod Right, but the “magical self-encoding” question is still extant.  EM frequencies encode nested 3D (and sound info) within themselves.  Pinhole camera is a great simple example: Light self-modulates and transmutes literally from some unrecognizable non-geometrically identifiable configuration into the encoded 2D image by organizing its particulates to do so right at the point of contact with a 2D/3D substrate.

Comment: @jstola since the question is speaking to EM data encoding, please forget about the raster scan as an example then... use a pinhole camera.

Comment: If you're changing the question to be about a pinhole camera then you're on the wrong site. Try physics or photography, because this is Electrical Engineering.

Comment: @jstola because it does? :)  is light maintaining a geometric configuration before it “draws” the image?... you can google pinhole cameras and see how they work.  In reality, same issue is with any lens refracting onto a CMOS.

Comment: @brhans pinhole camera just an example... applies to any engineered sensor really

Comment: @JordanFine a pinhole camera is not a funnel ... each photon does not need to be encoded with a destination coordinate ... each photon needs only to travel in a straight line and at a specific heading to pass through the pinhole and intersect the viewscreen ... the photon from a single point in the scene can intersect only a small area of the viewscreen ... there is no encoding of the scene involved

Comment: "any engineered sensor"? That's more than a little too broad. A photodiode? A thermocouple? A microphone? All 1D sensors. Just like the individual sensing elements which make up the pixels in a modern camera. Your "question" makes even less sense when applied to "any engineered sensor".

Comment: @jsotola EM waves encode data man.  Light is a self-encoding EM frequency.  Light strikes a scene and “records” the state of the scene, no different than any other modulated wave that has been encoded with data it is transmitting.

Comment: @brhans How so?  As I said above, EM waves get modulated, or encode data.  My question is applicable to the EM spectrum in general, but more specifically in the case of visible light, we can clearly see a continuous wave refracting into its discrete photons that transform to geometrically reflect what has been modulated when it hits the surface.  Radio waves are manually induced modulation (encoding) and visible light waves are self-induced.

Comment: @JordanFine I think that there is a miscommunication happening here ... it is possible that we are all talking about different things

Comment: @jsotola re: pinhole camera... I believe it’s a continuous wave going through the hole which is then refracted into the photons that  are aligning contiguously and perfectly to reflect a 2D image.  The light is maintaining dimensional consistency within itself no different than a sound wave stores constituent waves within itself dimensionally (spectrographically) to reflect the spatiality of the audio data.

Comment: @jsotola  maybe!

Comment: @JordanFine `photons that are aligning contiguously and perfectly to reflect a 2D image` ... wrong ... a photon that strikes a random point in the scene and reflects randomly, and if by luck happens to travel through the pinhole, that photon can strike only a small area on the viewscreen because of the small size of the pinhole ... this repeats over and over, in huge numbers ... there is no aligning contiguously to reflect the image, in fact, it is quite random ... sort of like rain falling through a hole in a roof ... it is all an exercise in geometry

Comment: @jsotola that’s describing a greater enigma then... as if there’ some stencil on the substrate and the photons hail-mary themselves into pre-ordained slots!  Where’s the image template??

Comment: @JordanFine  think of this ... apartment building 3 storeys high ... 3 apartments on each floor ... 9 windows all together on the front of the building ... house across the street from the apartment building ... one open window on front of house ... a sniper equiped with a paintball marker in each apartment window ... each sniper using a single color paintballs that is different from the other snipers ... the snipers start firing painballs through the house window and hitting the wall inside the house .......... think about the path of the paintballs and which part of the wall they will mark

Comment: @JordanFine I think I know where you may be headed and though I also think you have a serious question in mind, I also think the engineers here are mired in implementation details and not pulling themselves backward out of the hole to see the larger picture. (Sorry, puns are tempting now.) So you are at cross-purposes. I don't think I'll say anything more at all and just sit back and enjoy the show. ;)

Comment: @jsotola that works for the LIDAR-style scanning concept as mentioned below ... but the issue with say a pinhole camera is that each photon itself is becoming a sniper and coordinating with other snipers with some kind of aiming plan!

Comment: @jonk  uh huh :)  some are getting it...

Comment: @JordanFine the snipers are not coordinated in any way ... there is no aiming plan ... i was unclear ... the snipers simply fire randomly out their windows... only a small percentage of the paintballs actually hit the window at the house

Comment: But as Bruce mentioned below, essentially a lens is taking mathematically disparate particulates and dimensionally converging them to create an image that doesn’t exist prior to entering the lens!  Where is it??  The lens is organizing the photons to replicate a “stored image“...from where??

Comment: @JordanFine i am begining to think that you are talking about holograms, but you are being cryptic for some reason

Comment: @jsotola includes holograms, but, I’m discussing the nature of 2D and 3D info being encoded in 1D analog waves ( and ultimately discerned by a 1D physical processor AS 2D 3D that doesn’t know the difference).... check out jonk’s first response to see the gist of the mystery I’m probing

Comment: (Correction: as 2D or 3D, but doesn’t know the difference)

Comment: @JordanFine yes, i have read the comment about the possibility of living in 1D world ... it is not an impossible concept ... difficult to imagine though ... so, is this your question then? ...  `if we live in a 2D universe, and we employ a pinhole camera, where is the template for the resultant image stored?`

Comment: @jsotola ding ding ding! :)

Comment: @JordanFine that sounds like a difficult question to answer ... I suspect that you would have to compare a 3D pinhole camera to a 4D pinhole camera and extrapolate to 2D pinhole camera ... can't imagine a 4D camera ... the pinhole would be a sphere ... maybe that is what a black hole is, a 4D pinhole, and we live on a ground glass viewing screen ... lol

Comment: @jsotola I spent many many evenings with an active string theorist debating reality and using mathematics to do so. We each would teach the other about some new area of study (which I'm happy to say something I brought to the table impacted a full chapter of his recent book on string theory.) It was some of the more enjoyable times for me, as I acquired many new thoughts. I hate to see this discussion wind down. I've been having way way too much fun, so far. I suspect Jordan is an interesting character and would make for fun discussions. Oh well. Not here, I fear. ;) I wish the best for him.

Comment: Haha... no, I’m here! Fell asleep, sorry!... we should definitely talk some more.  Is it best to enter chat mode here?  They don’t like discussions in comments...

Comment: I had a similar experience with a guy online where we had a public discussion that was viewed by 20k.  Very fun.  I believe it can be proven that there is a 5D “spatializer” metaphysical component within the being,

Comment: ... if carefully crafted as a reductio ad absurdum argument, where one starts with the limitations of the physical grey matter as a 1D processor and then explores the nature of thought and a model for reason itself to arrive at a “by default” proof for a mind/brain duality (that is abandoned by mainstream science but was readily embraced by Leibniz, Newton, Des Cartes, etc).  There are two definitions of “dimension” being employed—informational dimension (“2D array”) and spatial dimension (2D picture in reality).

Comment: There is an “infinity interpolator” within the mind that interpolates discrete data into an indissociable 2D+ form, such as a 3D cube in the mind with 8 orthogonal corners and infinite Euclidean points.  The cube does not exist *as described* in the brain.  Where does it exist *as described*?  Where did the definition come from for it?  And as internal observer, we define ourselves as spatially 3D and can “pan around such” a shape as a conscious observer.  How and where is this being represented?

Answer (score 2):

Time is the dimension you are missing!

At the end of the day the video signal amplitude at any given moment represents brightness (and colour) at one point, but that point scans across quickly and down the screen slowly.

Both the phosphors decay time and the eyes flicker fusion frequency combine to give the impression of a complete image.

The geometry is encoded in the sync pulses (Negative going pulses that drop below the normal black level) that are detected to reset the scan circuits to the start of a line or top of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... problem is, the signal is self-organizing 2D data into a 1D stream via time and retains the 1D->2D correspondence as it transposes back to 2D.  How?

Comment: My question applies to the photons in a pin-hole camera .... the photons go through the tiny hole and then splay back into an inverted 2D image.  Where’s the transform function that instructs the photons to align in representation of the scene?

Comment: I think you need to edit your question to explain clearly what you are talking about.

Comment: @Transistor ✅ done

Comment: How is both brightness AND color (2 informational dimensions) being represented by any one 1D amplitude peak?

Comment: The video signal (in the frequency domain) has a brightness component in about the DC-4MHz or so region which encodes brightness, and a colour subcarrier at about 5MHz which encodes hue (as phase angle relative to a reference sent at the start of each line) and saturation (as amplitude). The receiver phase locks a crystal oscillator onto the reference burst and then does an IQ demodulation of the croma subcarrier to get two components which feed the matrix that produces RGB for the guns.

Comment: Right, 2D information encoded at a single amplitude which can be represented as a single binary number.  Waves act as 2D mobile databases.  A wave representing millions in a room is “flattened” into a single voltage value, and when we “view” it in a spectrometer, mysteriously we can “see” and “hear” any number of timbres that are FFT-extrapolated.  Where is the additional “depth” of values stored from a 1D brain’s perspective?

Answer (score 1):

> light is self-modulating to encode 3D scenery data perfectly **without**
> **external interference** to self-induce a modulation.

The only case I can think of where that is true is in a [hologram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holography), where [coherent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_(physics)#Spectral_coherence) light is split into 2 beams that interfere with *each other* (so technically not 'external' interference). Different path lengths to and from the 3D object 'modulate' the phases of the beams relative to each other, creating varying brightness when they interfere at the recording surface. this encodes the 3D image as a combination of Fresnal 'zone plates', which reproduce the image when illuminated by a point source.

In most optical imaging systems non-coherent light is focused by some external component which selectively bends, reflects or occludes the beams to produce an image on the 2D surface. This could be a lens, concave mirror, or pinhole. The focusing device uses the spatial *directions* of the beams to resolve the image. Without this 'external interference' no image is produced because the light is a mixture of photons with random frequencies and phases coming from all different directions.

A 1D image can be obtained by measuring the time taken for a pulse to reach the object and reflect back from it. This was how early RADAR worked, with only distance to the aircraft being shown. To get a 2D or 3D image the antenna must produce a narrow beam and be rotated to sweep across the sky. The other spatial dimensions are again encoded in the *direction* of the beam.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...  “In most optical imaging systems non-coherent light is focused by some external component which selectively bends, reflects or occludes the beams to produce an image on the 2D surface. “  right, so in the case of a lens, it is “intelligently” taking those photons and “configuring them” in 2D such that they two-dimensionally reflect the spatial data encoded in the wave!

Comment: I wouldn't say 'intelligently' but yes, the lens takes different beams radiating from one place and directs them to converge at another place. When focusing on distant objects the focal distance is proportionally compressed to 'squash' the image into 2 dimensions. A pinhole is less 'intelligent' - It simply discards all beams that are not coming (almost) directly from the object so it doesn't have to do any directing, and objects are always in 'focus' no matter how close or far away. Lenses also use the pinhole effect via the iris, which increases depth of field as it is made smaller.

Comment: Why not intelligent??  It knows what to do with different photons in different circumstances, fourier-transforming and aligning away!

Comment: @JordanFine  The lens is actually just applying a phase delay to the incoming EM field.  Due to how wave equations work, this causes the field to stop diverging and begin converging.  Without understanding a lot of math, why a simple phase delay causes this to happen is not going to make sense to you however.

Comment: The lens itself is not intelligent - it simply bends light according to its refractive index. The 'intelligence' is in the design of the lens elements, so it comes from the person who designed it. This applies to all other devices we create - we imbue them with some of our own intelligence!

Comment: @BruceAbbott Right, but the “bending” is hella nuts.  We basically have disparate particles that do not resemble an image and then do so after converging.  They are not organized as a discernible image...  this modulation is no different than  30GHz satellite tv signal embedding the 2D data

Comment: The refraction index is only modulating the image size... but it’s the  reproduction of the 2D image itself via the specific coordination of those non-mathematically dependent incoming photons that I’m interested in.

Comment: They don't coordinate (one photon per second would produce an image eventually), but they _are_ mathematically dependent - by geometry. The bending may seem 'hella nuts' but is a well understood property of waves. It also occurs in water waves and sound waves. The principles can be proved with basic geometry and physics, and are a direct result of the 3D world we live in.

Comment: @JordanFine Lenses work on all types of waves, not just light. An acoustic lens will focus sound and form an acoustic image. You keep mentioning photons, but lenses work on waves. Mathematically, a lens works by applying a different phase delay to each point on a wavefront. The difference in phase causes the wave to converge to an image. If the image is made of light, then photons are part of that wave, but people understood how lenses worked long before they knew about photons.

Comment: See the gist of my question above with jsotola.  “If we live in a 2D universe, and we employ a pinhole camera, where is the template for the resultant image stored?”

Comment: The data is 1D, the brain is a material 1D processor—where’s the 2D or 3D image as an indissociable unit?  Take a TV signal over time t... every point is a unique 1D oscillating value of voltage.  Where’s the 2D data stored?

Comment: @BruceAbbott “they are mathematically dependent by geometry”...  therefore light and EM waves in general have a mimetic, geometric bias.

Comment: @BruceAbbott   Also, aren’t where they “land” considered a probability metric?  How is the lens “guaranteeing” a repeatable, contiguous arrangement of photons to composite a 2D image onto a substrate?

Answer (score 1):

> photons go through the tiny hole and then splay back into an inverted 2D image

The answer is more readily found when the photons are treated as waves rather than particles. In a real-life scene there are waves (photons) coming from every angle, and those can be treated as mathematically independent, so lets focus (no pun intended) on a wave coming straight on the axis of your pinhole camera. That electromagnetic wave, having come from a far-away point source (say, a star), is essentially a spherical wavefront, but because the hole is so small it can be treated as "flat" or having uniform field strength, and the strength of the wave is uniform across the hole. (You can see this by putting a ring on a soccer ball -- a small ring allows you to see an approximately "flat" surface within the ring, but with a larger ring the curvature of the ball becomes obvious.)

Since the field strength at the focus (the back of the camera) is the 2d Fourier transform of the field at the hole (essentially uniformly flat), the light resolves to a point in the 2d-plane (that is, its a Dirac impulse function in two dimensions). Thus, the light from the star resolves to a single (spatial) impulse, which is a point of light, on the back of the camera.

This math can be applied independently, to every star in the sky, but accounting for the angle of arrival, so the image is created with little dots of light spread out across the back of the camera. As you get further off center, the approximation of "flat" and "uniform" (on the hole) becomes less and less true, so the edge of the image is fuzzy.

With a larger opening, the approximation of "flat" also begins to fail. Using a lens is actually compensating for a specific curvature of the field, so source that are too-far and too-near don't quite fit the equation, giving the lens a "depth of field". Shrink the aperture (make the useful hole in the lens smaller), and depth of field increases. A 3d camera takes advantage of this by effectively measuring the curvature of the field.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... “ In a real-life scene there are waves (photons) coming from every angle, and those can be treated as mathematically independent, lets focus (no pun intended) on a wave coming straight on the axis of your pinhole camera.“  But there are myriad waves require to produce the image... are they not self-organizing to reflect the spatial information?  If they’re mathematically independent, how is a mathematically cohesive image formed?  The waves somehow “know” to contiguously align ... they bear no resemblance to the image in mid-air—as they don’t as electrons down a wire

Comment: Actually, in the case of pinhole camera, they do bear a resemblance to the image mid air, if you look behind the pinhole. In front of the pinhole they still do, but are buried among infinite other rays that do not contribute to the image so you don't see an image mid air.

Comment: @chamod I meant in front of the pin hole, yeah... “they do not contribute to the image” implies the refraction process is filtering to a bias of 2D image formation/replication

Answer (score 1):

> My question is applicable to the EM spectrum in general, but more specifically in the case of visible light, we can clearly see a continuous wave refracting into its discrete photons that transform to geometrically reflect what has been modulated when it hits the surface. Radio waves are manually induced modulation (encoding) and visible light waves are self-induced.

Other people have explained image formation abstractly, but I can give you a good example of how a 1D (transverse) wave can be modulated to form a 2D image.

Imagine a LIDAR/SONAR/RADAR scanner composed of a transmitter sending out a beam of radiation (light, sound, whatever) and a receiver (could be a lens, microphone, etc) pointed in the same direction.  As the transmitter rotates, it will scan a line of energy across the surroundings.  As the scanner passes over an object, it will reflect signal back in proportion to its reflectivity.  This modulates the return signal with information about each point's reflectivity.  The receiver will then detect this modulated signal, and color in a pixel in proportion to how much signal it receives.  Gradually you can built up first a 1D line of pixels and then a 2D image.

This is imaging using raster scanning (1 point at a time), but if you just get two receivers side by side, you can map out two adjacent pixels for each location you point at.  Get 4 pixels and you can map out 4 at once.  Get 10 million and you can map out an entire 10 megapixel image in one shot.  Each receiver is detecting a single 1D signal, and each signal is modulated by the reflectivity of whatever it is pointed at.

Now if you want to know why each receiver can detect a different point in the scene without them all seeing the same point (or maybe the sum of all points at once), you need to understand diffraction and Fourier optics (which other answers have addressed).  But conceptually, it should be clear that if you have N receivers each pointed in a slightly different direction, you should be able to receive N modulated signals in parallel.

**EDIT**

> Thanks for the answer... how do you apply such logic to the image created by a pin-hole camera?

The pinhole camera is the 2D array example above (lots of parallel receivers), each pointed through the pinhole.  Since the area around the pinhole completely blocks signal, each receiver can only receive signal from one spot through the pinhole. That the modulation from that spot is what it records.

You can actually draw this pretty easy.  Imagine a 2x2 pixel sensor behind a pinhole.  Draw a line with a ruler from each pixel on the sensor through the pinhole.  You'll see that each strikes a different point in the surrounding scene.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... how do you apply such logic to the image created by a pin-hole camera?

Comment: @JordanFine Edited.

Comment: As Bruce said above, a lens is converging those pixels — just the ones needed to create a contiguous 2D replication.  Point being, only until refracted, there is no observable mathematical interdependency of the photons... you cannot see the image mid-air until the lens “instructs” the photons to reconfigure into a 2D image... until such time, the photons are independent of each other...there is no explanation for this I can see.